# Uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code, which I use to customize form_for. I need to inherit ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag

```
class InstanceTag < ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag
```

I get exception after the upgrade to Rails 4 and I saw that in the docs there is no such class.
What is the best class to use instead of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research. I found that

```
ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag
```

is transformed into module called **ActiveModelInstanceTag**

```
ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelInstanceTag
```

Comment: Did you ever find out *why* it was renamed?  Thanks.

Comment: actually no. sorry :/