# Rails 3.2 to 5 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag.new is not accepting the arguments what would be the alternate for this From rails3.2 to 5

```
ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag.new(arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

This pops out an error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0))
```

Comment: did you able to find it's solution?

Answer (score 3):

The class was deprecated/renamed in the upgrade to rails 4. The class `ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag` 
is transformed into module called `ActiveModelInstanceTag`. Full qualifier:

```
ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelInstanceTag
```

Source: [Uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409891/uninitialized-constant-actionviewhelpersinstancetag-in-rails-4)

Comment: Yes i do see but i cannot do a .new operation on it get the object generated according like div tag or span tag Because it says


ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelInstanceTag.new(arg1,arg2,arg3,{}) 

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelInstanceTag:Module

```

Comment: @nathanvda I'm also stuck in same issue. did you people find any solution for this problem?

Comment: The module in included in other clases like ActionView::Helpers::Tags::Base. You can instantiate an instance with ActionView::Helpers::Tags::Base.new if it fits your needs.